# My sql prevent duplicate inserts in lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql script where I insert values to a type_table. If I execute this script again duplicate values will be inserted in type_table. I don't want to delete the type_table and re-insert because the id is foreign key for many other tables. How do I execute Insert statement only once assuming this script will be executed many times. It's kind of a lookup table that you populate only once in the beginning.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type_table` (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_text` VARCHAR(200),
  `create_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   INDEX (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `type_table` (`create_time`,`type_text`) VALUES 
 (now(), 'type1' ),
 (now(), 'type2' );
```

Comment: ``index(`id`)`` is redundant. a primary key is ALREADY an index. and if you don't want dupe values inserted, then you'll have to add a unique index to catch those inserts. right now your only unique index is the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set 'type_text' as a unique column in database to simply not allowing duplicate values

Comment: I thought about that but it then throws error which is I guess okay as long as it works. I was more looking for adding IF else check but I couldn't do it inside script unless it is a procedure.